# Retrieve variable from instance of Django form

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a Django form `NameForm`. I am attempting to iterate over an array of values and, for each value, have an option to display the same form. The only thing that should change with the form submission should be the associated value to which the form is displayed next to.

This becomes much clearer with an example. For some array `[1,2,3]` we should display:
[image: an example display]

We can then click on any `open form` icon, fill out the `NameForm` form. The resultant information, including the `form_id` (in this case `1, 2, or 3`) should be returned to **forms.py**. How can I fetch the `form_id` variable from an instance of `NameForm` in **index.py**?

My (hacky) attempt can be found below. The problem is I don't know how to access the `form_id` variable I created in the `NameForm` object.

**forms.py**

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    form_id = None
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=3)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        form_id = form.form_id # The problem line, as form_id is always None
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse( \
            ' '.join((str(form.cleaned_data['your_name']),form_id ))\
            ) #Throws TypeError as can't join None and string
    else:
        forms = []
        vals = [1,2,3]
        for val in vals:
            form = NameForm()
            form.form_id = val
            forms.append(form)
    return render(request, 'post/index.html', {'forms': forms})
```

**index.html**

```
    {%for form in forms%}
    {{form.form_id}}
    <button class="button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
    <div class="myForm">
        <form class="form-container" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <button class="button" onclick="closeForm()">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </br>
    {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django Form or Django Model, when you set a field's value to `None`, it is assumed that you want to ignore said field. This is helpful when creating a model that inherits from another model and you want to remove some unnecessary fields.

If you want to set value for a field on Form creation, you should pass it into `__init__` method. E.g:

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    form_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=3)

    def __init__(self, form_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['form_id'].initial = form_id
```

Alternatively, instead of overriding the `__init__` method, you can set an initial value for `form_id` when you create an instance of `NameForm`. For example:

```
vals = [1,2,3]
forms = [NameForm(initial={'form_id': val}) for val in vals]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The problem with this is that the user can then edit the `form_id` field. One can of course change the definition of `form_id` to `forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())` however this still does not work as the resultant `form_id` value is always `vals[0]`.

Comment: I can't see the details how you setup the form and use it in the view. But in my side, I still can get the right ```form_id``` sent from client side. ```form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['form_id'])```. My template and the view is the same as yours.

Comment: You were correct! The problem was I then had to pass which form to open to my `js` code. Escaping both html and js was a pain but if anyone is curious, the syntax was: `onclick= "openForm('{{form.form_id.value|escapejs}}'); "`